# jQuery validator additional method not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, validation

I am using this jQuery validation plugin, http://jqueryvalidation.org/  And I am creating an addition method, as shown here.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod('exists', function(value, element) {
    $.ajax({
        data: {username: value},
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'action/check/',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            if (data==true) {
                console.log(data);
                return true;
            }
            if (data==false) {
                console.log(data);
                return false;
            }
        }
    })
}, 'This username is already in use');
```

My console is getting the proper data back from the check script and in my console I can see true and false etc.  But what I do not understand is the validation flag seems to flag the input regardless of what the input is.

```
rules: {
        password_confirm: {
            equalTo: 'input[name=password]'
        },
        username: {
            exists: true
        }
    }
```

I already have username `chris` in my database, so when I type `chris` into the username input I should get a flag for being a duplicate user, but regardless of what type I get the validation flag.

What am I missing

Comment: You can't return a value from an ajax method as you have given... since you want to do a ajax based validation use the existing remote rule

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your validation won't work because it is asynchronous(ajax request).

You can use the existing [remote rule](http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/) to do that, make sure your request is returning true/false as its result

```
  rules: {
    password_confirm: {
      equalTo: 'input[name=password]'
    },
    username: {
      remote: {
        url: 'action/check/',
        type: 'POST'
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    jQuery.validator.addMethod('exists', function(value, element) {

         var result = false;

         $.ajax({
            data: {username: value},
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'action/check/',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                result = data; // make sure data returns bool value
            }
        });

        return result;
    }, 'This username is already in use');
```